# java GC algorithm fine tuning : CMS algorithm alone & combination

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, concurrent-mark-sweep

Currently I am using a combination of CMS and ParNewGC

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

As per my understanding, CMS is used for Old Gen GC and UserPareNewGC used for you gen garbage collection.

If I pass only CMS as single parameter,  `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`, ***is CMS used for garbage collection of both young gen and Old Gen?***

I think that `UseParNewGC` still used for young gen even though it has not been configured along with CMS. But I want to confirm the assumption.

Am I right?

**EDIT:** I am using ***JDK 1.7 version***. If behaviour is different in **1.7 and 1.8**, please explain.

Comment: Which JVM implementation and version are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking gc questions you should state what version of the jdk you are wondering about since the actual combination varies from version to version.
But, CMS is only used with tenured generation, never with young generation.
Parallell New Gen scavenge will be used.

Comment: Updated question with jdk version

Answer (score 1):

> I think that UseParNewGC still used for young gen even though it has not been configured along with CMS. But I want to confirm the assumption.

You can always determine the *effective* flags by appending `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to the command line.

This will allow you to determine whether changing flag A will influence flag B.

Comment: I have added above flag but I did not get any concrete proof on which algorithm is executed -  [Parallel Time: 168.2 ms, GC Workers: 23]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 82247.9, Avg: 82254.2, Max: 82256.4, Diff: 8.5]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 17.4, Avg: 21.7, Max: 27.6, Diff: 10.2, Sum: 498.2]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.7, Max: 4.4, Diff: 4.4, Sum: 15.1]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 4.8, Max: 30, Diff: 30, Sum: 110]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.2, Avg: 0.4, Max: 1.5, Diff: 1.3, Sum: 9.1]

Comment: diff the console output of `java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` and `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`